# Conditional category & tag statement

Tags: categories, tags, conditional-tags

I'm just working on a "quick" change to the blog-entry-subtitle of specific posts in a category on my wordpress website. I'm hoping to have "Published in Orchard and Vine Magazine on:" instead of "Posted on:".

You'll see that the page I'm [trying to customize is here](http://averylawoffice.ca/category/legal-libation-columns)

```
<?php if ( is_category('Legal Libation Columns') ) : ?>
    <h2 class="blog-entry-subtitle">Published in Orchard and Vine Magazine on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></h2>
<?php  else: ?>
    <h2 class="blog-entry-subtitle">Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

GREAT! I love it. However once you click on one of those posts to read more it converts the blog-entry-subtitle back to the "Posted on:" as now you aren't in the specific category anymore.

I would like the "Published in Orchard and Vine Magazine on:" instead of "Posted on:" for all posts with a category and tag of Legal Libation Columns. So then I try this.

```
<?php if (is_category('Legal Libation Columns') && has_tag('Legal Libation Columns')); ?>    
    <h2 class="blog-entry-subtitle">Published in Orchard and Vine Magazine on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></h2>
<?php  else: ?>
    <h2 class="blog-entry-subtitle">Posted on: <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?></h2>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However I get a weird white screen of nothing? 
[image]

How do I have it so that any post with the tag Legal Libation Columns always has that specific blog-entry-subtitle without giving me an error?

Comment: What do you mean by breaking the site, according to me and many others, this means a white screen of death. What debug info do you get. You are saying "category and tag", so your operator is wrong, `||` should be `&&`

Comment: I had used && but it gave me a white screen? See updated question.

Comment: In the first line `;` is in the end. There should be `:`. This is causing white screen of death. `<?php if (is_category('Legal Libation Columns') && has_tag('Legal Libation Columns')): ?>  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem lies in [`is_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_category). This conditional check if you are on a category page, not if a post belongs to a category.

To check if a post belongs to a category, you should be using [`has_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category)

So your conditional statement should be

```
<?php if (has_category('Legal Libation Columns') && has_tag('Legal Libation Columns')): ?>
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Nilambar, there is a syntax error as well in your code as he said

Here are some tips

- Don't use `:` and `endif`. If makes code difficult to read and it is not code editor friendly. Rather use curly brackets `{}`
- When developing themes and plugings, or just make changes to a site, set debug to true. Such errors is easy recognizable with debug set to true. Please take the time and read [**Debugging in Wordpress**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)
- Always indent your code properly to make it easier to read and follow

Comment: Thanks for all of this. Will be fixing it up with your suggestion as well. One more thing, i there a way to have the Previous and Next buttons only go through the specific category as opposed to both the category and the blog?

Comment: My pleasure. Sure, although it is gong out of scope for this question :-). Go and have a look at [`next_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [`previous_post_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) Just set `$in_same_term = false` argument to `$in_same_term = true`

Comment: Thanks. I started a new topic for more guidance on the post links - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/155486/looking-to-exclude-blog-posts-from-category-previous-next-buttons.